# Importing slim model in tensorflow c++

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have a network model defined using slim library in python tensorflow.
Now I want to port it to c++. However it seems to me that tensorflow.contrib.slim is a python only library. How could I use it in my c++ software?

Basically I have something like:

```
        self.conv1 = slim.convolution2d( \
            inputs=self.imageIn,num_outputs=32,\
            kernel_size=[8,8],stride=[4,4],padding='VALID', \
            biases_initializer=None,scope=myScope+'_conv1')
```

How could I implement this in c++ tensorflow?

At the moment I'm trying to replace slim implementation with plain tensorflow, and then going c++. However replacing

```
self.conv1 = slim.convolution2d( \
            inputs=self.imageIn,num_outputs=32,\
            kernel_size=[8,8],stride=[1,4,4,1],padding='VALID', \
            biases_initializer=None, weights_initializer=_initializer, scope=myScope+'_conv1')
```

with plain tf

```
with tf.variable_scope(myScope+'_conv1'):
            weights = tf.get_variable("weights",[8, 8, 3, 32],
            initializer=_initializer,  dtype=tf.float32)

            self.conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(self.imageIn, weights, [1, 4, 4, 1], padding='VALID')
```

in a working model produces a mess: nothing works anymore. What am I forgetting?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Most of TensorFlow's high-level graph building infrastructure is in Python. However, you can build the graph in Python and [export to C++](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/README.md). I would recommend that at the moment, rather than building a model in C++ from scratch.

Comment: @AllenLavoie let's suppose the app I'm porting is https://github.com/awjuliani/DeepRL-Agents/blob/master/Deep-Recurrent-Q-Network.ipynb . Please, have a look at the testing section.. Even if I export the graph, In order to make predictions I need to create the network..

Comment: Can you construct the prediction network in Python exactly as it will be used, then export that rather than the training network?

Comment: @AllenLavoie yes, that would meet requirements. However in my case I wonder how I can do it, since in c++ I won't have access to, let's say, rnn_state ... isn't it?

Comment: Ah, yes, you do need some coordination so that C++ knows the names of the Tensors which will be used. There is a bit of infrastructure to help with this in the form of tags (mostly targeted at serving). I'd browse through the [C++](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader_test.cc#L114) and [Python](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/saved_model_test.py) unit tests for examples. Or you can just retrieve the Tensor by name directly with session::run in C++.